# MATLAB - keep subplot in panel when zooming or moving camera position

Tags: matlab, subplot

I am making a GUI in MATLAB with a subplot in a panel. My problem is that if the user try to zoom in the subplot, it will became bigger and take over the whole GUI. The same behavior happens if I try to move the camera position in the subplot.

Is there a way to constraint the subplot within my panel?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a 2D or 3D plot? In my experience, only three dimensional plots behave in this manner. Try zooming in an XY view, and then rotating.

Comment: It's quite funny at how a coworker just asked me the exact same question. It's also funny that i don't have an answer! I'll try to find you both an answer!

Comment: I forgot to mention it is a 3D plot.

Comment: @Doresoom, zooming in XY view could work, but it doesn't solve the problem if I change the camera position.

Comment: I did more research and this seems to be a bug of the clipping property of the uipanel. This is really annoying.

Comment: I'm still looking. I found a MATLAB forum entry about this but no answer: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56637-when-zooming-3d-plotted-data-exceeds-uipanel-extent-despite-axes-being-clipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea would be to put your subplot in background and to have panels (with 0 margin) that go around your subplot. This way, you wouldn't see the subplot take all the GUI space.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. My subplot has already the panel as parent, but zooming or moving the camera position caused the subplot to go over other panels.

Comment: Did you check the panel order (front, back, etc.)?

Comment: I didn't knew you could do that. Using `uistack(mypanel,'bottom')` puts the panel behind the others so that when the subplot goes bigger than the panel, it shows behind the others panels. It is a good idea, but the subplot still goes outside the panel. Still, best solution so far. Thanks!

Comment: After a month, I found out that it is a real problem of MATLAB clipping property. I ended up doing exactly what you said.